# Prove, that $\lim_{x \to \infty} 2^x \sin(\pi/(2^k))$ converges to $\pi$.

Tags: calculus, limits, area

Prove, that $$\lim_{x \to \infty} 2^x \sin\left(\frac \pi {2^x}\right)=\pi.$$

I've tried calculus to no avail.

I found out that every element of this sequence is the area of a regular rectangle with $2^{k+2}$  sides that's inside a circle whose radius is 1, therefor the function is monotonically rising and every time smaller than $\pi\cdot 1^2=\pi$.

Is there a simpler way?

Comment: is n't this sin(pi/2^x)??

Comment: Something looks odd: $\;\sin\frac\pi{2^k}\;$ is a constant, and $\;2^x\xrightarrow [x\to\infty]{}\infty\;$ ...that $\;k\;$ seems to be $\;x\;$

Comment: I messed up but you people have helped me nonetheless. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Substitute $y\equiv\pi/2^x$. As $x\to\infty$, $y\to0$ from above. Hence, $$\lim_{x\to\infty}2^x\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2^x}\right)=\lim_{y\to0}\frac{\pi}{y}\sin(y)=\pi\lim_{y\to0}\frac{\sin y}{y}=\pi\times 1=\pi.$$

Answer (score 3):

Hints assuming $\;k=x\;$ :

$$\frac\pi{2^x}\xrightarrow[x\to\infty]{}0$$

$$2^x\sin\frac\pi{2^x}=\pi\frac{\sin\frac\pi{2^x}}{\frac\pi{2^x}}\xrightarrow[x\to 0]{}\ldots?$$

Answer (score 2):

**Hint** Correct the typo and use 
$$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sin x}{x}=1$$

Answer (score 2):

Using $\sin$'s MacLaurin series,
\begin{align}
\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty} \  2^x\sin\frac{\pi}{2^x} &=  \lim_{x\rightarrow\infty} \  2^x\left(\frac{\pi}{2^x} - \frac{\pi^3}{3! \cdot 2^{3x}} +  \frac{\pi^5}{5! \cdot 2^{5x} } + \ \ldots\right) \\
& = \lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}  \ \pi - \frac{\pi^3}{3! \cdot 2^{2x}} +  \frac{\pi^5}{5! \cdot 2^{4x} } + \ \ldots \\
& = \pi 
\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

The question should be $2^xsin(\frac{\pi}{2^x})$. Apply L'Hospital rule.